# how to apply on certain condition and append value inside it separated by - in pandas through python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe which contains the columns `Name` and `Mains`.

```
data = [['Anshu', '8321-1328-11'], ['Hero', '83211-1128-11'], ['Naman', '65432-8765-4']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Mains'])
```

I want to update the Mains column into a new column with an updated value i.e. df['new_mains'] with the following condition: if the number is seprated by 4-4-2, then should be added with 0 and updated separated number will be 5-4-2? is it possible to do so in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure it could be done. For example,

```
def my_func(strn):

    a,b,c = strn.split('-')
    new_a = '0'+a if len(a)==4 else a
    new_b = '0'+b if len(b)==3 else b
    new_c = '9'+c if len(c)==1 else c

    return '-'.join([new_a,new_b,new_c])
```

And then,

```
df['New_Mains'] = df['Mains'].apply(my_func)
```

Note: Going off the assumption 'a' is either of length 4 or 5. If 'a', 'b', 'c' are of any other length then, you can also do something like (works for current scenario as well)

```
new_a = '0'*5-len(a) + a
new_b = '0'*4-len(b) + b
new_c = '9'*2-len(c) + c
```

More on [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) here. Basically, in your case the string reads something like "99999-9999-99" with "-" as a separator. So,

```
"99999-9999-99".split('-') #would return
['99999', '9999', '99']
```

where a = '99999', b = '9999', c = '99'.

new_a, new_b, new_c are variables to hold new values of a, b and c after checking for the conditional statements. Finally join the strings new_a, new_b, new_c to look like original strings from 'Mains' column. More on [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Thanks @hkr its working can u explain what actually a,b,c and new_a, new_b, new_c is working how actually its storing and procssing